# Calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}{(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\cos\phi)^l \cdot 2i\sin(m\phi)\,d\phi}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I want to evaluate
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}
\left[\cos\left(\theta\right) + {\rm i}\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)\right]^{\,\ell}\ 2{\rm i}\sin\left(m\phi\right)\,{\rm d}\phi\ \mbox{where}\ \ell,m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}
$$
If i put values for $\ell$ and $m$ like $1$ and $2$ (for example), the integral is zero when I evaluate this in a calculator so i suspect the integral is zero: I tried to prove this but since there is a polynomial of degree $\ell$ and the sine function is evaluated in $m\phi$, I failed to do this. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: use that the integrand is periodic with period $2\pi$ so the integral transforms to same on $[-\pi, \pi]$ and then the integrand is odd so the integral is trivially zero

Comment: @Conrad the period of the integrad still is $2\pi$ if the sine function is evaluated in $m\phi$?

Comment: sin $mx$ has (lowest) period $2\pi/m$ but $2\pi$ is still a period for any $m$ so the integral is still periodic with period $2\pi$

Comment: @Conrad thanks!